# VS Program works in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, flycapture

I'm creating a program in visual studio using the fly capture camera libraries. My goal is to build the program into a standalone application. When run in debug mode the program behaves normally, but in release mode I get a 'System.IO.FileNotFoundExeception':

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FlyCapture2Managed_v140.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

So I'm missing a dll file, but why do I only get this error in release mode? How can I properly link the file in visual studios?

Comment: "or one of its dependencies" would be a likely explanation whenever you work with a camera.  Be sure to copy any firmware DLLs with a post-build event, copy-paste the one you use in the Debug build into the one for the Release build.  Do avoid forcing us to guess at this.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you reference me to an article/video where I can learn to do this? I'm new to visual studios.

Answer (score 5):

Check uour configuration, you just need to desactivate OptimzeCode.

1-Right click on your Project, click on Properties
2-go to tabItem Build, in section General desactivate Optimize Code.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you right click on the reference, select properties, then set 'Copy Local' to True it will be published when you release a build.

Answer (score 1):

Check your configuration, it may well be that you release configuration isn't set to build the project that produces 'FlyCapture2Managed_v140.dll'.

Right-click on your solution, select Configuration Manager, choose Release configuration and confirm the project has the Build column ticked.

Comment: Yep, looks good - in which case I assume your reference is an external one, in which case see Sean T's answer and try that. If not, then I would suggest posting your project file.